# how can i change my program to accept different inputs?

Tags: java, string, int

i have an absolute value program and as of right now it accepts numbers like 1 +1 -1 but i also need it to be able to accept decimals as valid inputs from the user. i also need to use the intString.matches method. how would i go about doing that?
here is the code im supposed to redo

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class absolutevalue {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

  System.out.print(" Type in a number  ");
  String inStr = input.nextLine();

  if (inStr.matches("//d"))
   System.out.println("The absolute value is" +inStr);
  else
    System.out.println("not even close");
   input.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Try this: double num = Double.parseDouble(in.next());

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: i have to redo it but idk where to start. this is what i have. i know i need to put something like if (inString.matches(//d etc) but im not 100% on the expressions inside the parentheses

Comment: i changed my code a bit so you guys might understand what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
Float num = input.nextFloat();
```

Your code will be like that...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AbsoluteValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(" Type in a number  ");
        Float num = input.nextFloat();

        if (num < 0) {
            num = num * -1;
        }

        System.out.println("The absolute value is " + num);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept **String, double, float, big decimal, boolean** from user with small change like :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class absolutevalue {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

  System.out.print(" Type in a number  ");
  int num = input.nextInt(); // for Int.
  String str = input.next(); // for String.
  String str = input.nextLine(); // for line of String.
  double num = input.nextDouble(); // for double.
  float str = input.nextFloat(); // for float.

  if (num <0){
    num = num * -1;
  }

  System.out.println("The absolute value is " + num);
   input.close();
 }
}
```